# File loop: read file into NSString, thats id is the filename ( without .txt)

Tags: ios, xcode, file-read

I have a loop, that gets all files at a dir. Now I want to read every single file, each into a var, thats identifier is the filename without ending.

for example:

filename is text.txt 
now read content into NSString *"text" .

Here is my code example: Can someone help?

```
// create loop to read all files:
NSFileManager* fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];

NSDirectoryEnumerator* en = [fileManager enumeratorAtPath:directoryTMP];

NSString* file;
while (file = [en nextObject])
{
   NSLog(@"File To Read : %@",file);

   if([file isEqualToString:@"do_not_read_this.txt"])
   {
     NSLog(@"Skip this file for reading");
   }
else
   {
   // read file here:
   NSString *fileNameToRead = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.txt",directoryTMPeJL,file];

   NSString *fileNameWithoutEnd = [file stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@".txt" withString: @""];

   // Read data from Dir
   NSString *<fileNameWithoutEnd> = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fileNameToRead
                                                                            usedEncoding:nil
                                                                                   error:nil];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you cannot create named variables at runtime, but you could read the files into a `NSMutableDictionary` where the key is the filename (without the extension) and the value (object) is the file data:

```
// create loop to read all files:
NSMutableDictionary *files = [NSMutableDictionary new];
NSFileManager* fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];

NSDirectoryEnumerator* en = [fileManager enumeratorAtPath:directoryTMP];

NSString* file;
while (file = [en nextObject])
{
   NSLog(@"File To Read : %@",file);

   if([file isEqualToString:@"do_not_read_this.txt"])
   {
     NSLog(@"Skip this file for reading");
   }
   else
   {
       // read file here:
       NSString *fileNameToRead = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.txt",directoryTMPeJL,file];

       NSString *fileNameWithoutEnd = [file stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@".txt" withString: @""];

       // Read data from Dir
       NSError *error = nil;
       NSString *data = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fileNameToRead
                                                        encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                           error:&error];
      if (data) {
          files[fileNameWithoutEnd] = data;
      } else {
          NSLog(@"Failed to read file '%@': %@", fileNameToRead, [error localizedDescription]);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: perfect! thats exactly what I was trying to do! Thank you!